# Observer is not working when updating records in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am facing a problem when using Observers in Rails 2.3.11. When I am creating a new object the observer is called and I get "Testing create" in my log file whereas when I am updating the object my observer is not called. May I know where I am going wrong. My model name is Termsmilestone.

```
class TermsmilestoneObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

    def after_update(termsmilestone)
      Rails.logger.info("Testing Update *****************")
    end

    def after_create(termsmilestone)
      Rails.logger.info("Testing create")
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I don't have a specific answer for you, we've used `Observers` in Rails 4 in this way:

--

```
#config/application.rb
...
config.active_record.observers = :your_observer


#app/models/your_observer.rb
class YourObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
   def after_save(your)
      ...
   end
end
```

--

This works for us in Rails 4 - I'm not sure about Rails 3 - but this works for us

Comment: The observer is working fine. Its just that in case of update the observer is not working whereas when I create a new object the observer is working. That is what I wanted to know. A little research helped me though. The callbacks are specific which means if I save the object by method save then update functions in my observer wont be executed whereas if I use update or update_attributes function then in that case the update callback works. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: No problem - I remember having a terribly difficult time finding the information I needed on observers; felt my experience could benefit